# Problem with Oracle and laravel does not load all records

Tags: php, laravel, oracle

I have a table in my Oracle database that has more than 500000 records when I make a User->take(1000)->get() it works but when I try to bring more than 1000 records it does not work, therefore when I do it with User:all();

Comment: Does it work when you manually write a query in the server console?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are there any errors returned when you are attempting to load more than 1000 rows?

Comment: if it works when I do it from the server it brings a total of 250605 records

Comment: Can you show the query builder code when you are requesting more than 1000 rows please?